# Kusto query not returning result in side Logic app

Tags: azure-logic-apps, azure-data-explorer

I have one logic app which will received Http request then will run query in Kusto to get detail based on an Id which will come from Http request output.
Now issue is that when kusto query runs it return  output as null []. When I run the same query in the kusto explore I am able to get the data.

Can anyone help me to figure it out what is issue here..?

Note: this logic app is called from a ymal pipeline to create bug when task is failed.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can it be that the parse json is not finding the values it expects? What does it do?

Comment: @Avnera Issue within azure data explore because kusto query is not returning result parse json is the 2 step. when I will get data from kusto query parse json  will parse it properly.

Comment: If so, it means that the query you are running in Kusto explorer is not the same as run by the logic app. To debug run ".show queries" and find the query that is sent by the logic app (use the "Application" column), copy it and try to run it in Kusto explorer, this will allow you to find the issue.

Comment: @Avnera Would like to inform you I'm copying query from logic app ones it generates then I try to run the same query in kusto explore both are same no differences in the query

Comment: It's strange, could you please check if you use the right api connection in your logic app. When you add the "Run query....." action, it will generate an api connection in the same resource group of your logic app. And if you add the "Run query...." action again, it will use the same api connection directly. So please check if you use the right api connection for your "Run query..." action. You can delete the original api connection first and then add the "Run query..." action again.

Comment: @Gaurav - did you find the queries in .show queries?

Comment: Any update ? Have you solve the problem ?

Comment: Hi I couldn't find any solution yet.@Avnera can you please tell me where I can see .show queries option..? @Hury Shen as i mentioned that I have pipeline where I am doing some  LCS 365 environment deployment which takes around 3 hrs to complete if they failed then pipeline PowerShell will call my logic app. Now pipeline calling logic app with all the required  parameters though its getting data from the database via kusto. I'm thinking it could be due to delay in the process. or one thing I tell you my logic app has different resource group and subscription & my VM's has different resource grp

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution of issue Kusto query not returning the result in Logic app.
The issue with Kusto. I was reading more about kusto and got to know that kusto query takes 10-15 minutes to load the data in to the database. That was the reason I was not getting any output from the logic app as this is being called from the release pipeline when something goes wrong in the pipeline immediately logic app calls the kusto query which return null as output. Now when I put delay in the  logic app I'm getting expected result.

Comment: how are you adding delay in the logic app?